# How to get current week data till today's date using query?

Tags: mysql

How to fetch current week data till today's date ?

Example - Current week start from 2017-08-01 to 2017-08-07 and today date is 2017-08-03. I want to fetch data from 2017-08-01 to 2017-08-03 using query.

```
This is query - 

SELECT *
    FROM   user_data
    WHERE  YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

Comment: `where datecol >= '2017-08-01'` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for reply. in this scenario i need to fetch start date of week and pass it in query. Is it possible to pass without any date ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it returns all the data after 2017-08-01 not current week.

Comment: `AND date <= CURDATE()`

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved my problem.

```
SELECT *
FROM   current_week
WHERE  YEARWEEK(`dt`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) and dt <= curdate() order by dt
```

This is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This one gets tricky in the last and first weeks of calendar years.

First you need to decide whether your week starts on Sunday or Monday. That is based on your national jurisdiction's business practices. In North America, it's generally Sunday. In Europe it is sometimes Monday.

You need an expression that computes the first moment of a calendar week based on a date.

This is such an expression for weeks starting Sunday.

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -1, 7))
```

This is it for weeks starting Monday. (Notice the `-2`.)

```
FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -2, 7))
```

Now you can select stuff from your table that's in the current week.

```
 SELECT whatever, whatever
   FROM user_data
  WHERE `date` >= FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -1, 7))
```

If you want stuff from the week before the current week use this

```
 SELECT whatever, whatever
   FROM user_data
  WHERE `date` >= FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -1, 7)) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   AND  `date` <  FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -MOD(TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) -1, 7))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, this query return all current week date.

Comment: SELECT * FROM current_week WHERE YEARWEEK(dt, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) and dt <= curdate() order by dt this query is working.